# XSLT xsl:for-each does only first row

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML, which I'm giving to an XSLT stylesheet to do some transformations but somehow the xsl:for-each only loops trough the first node...

I'm expecting it to loop trough all the nodes and transform them, but somehow it only loops trough the first value, not sure what I'm doing wrong here..

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<email>
    <uid>66</uid>
    <subject>You have been added to a Priooo project</subject>
    <message/>
    <arguments>
        <argument>
            <name>
                -url-
            </name>
            <value>
                http://localhost/iaf4asap/#/resetpassword/c0a82001--6b0373de_15eb8270a5e_-7fea</value>
            </argument>
            <argument>
                <name>
                    -inviteBy-
                </name>
                <value>Laurens Makel</value>
            </argument>
            <argument>
                <name>
                    -project-
                </name>
                <value>junkspam0003@outlook.com</value>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    <templateId>
        c02f1e50-d569-41d9-87ec-933cded8a330
    </templateId>
</email>
```

and this is my XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>


    <xsl:template match="/email">
    <email>
            <uniqueArguments>
                 <xsl:for-each select="arguments">
                    <uniqueArgument>
                        <name><xsl:value-of select="argument/name"/></name>
                        <value><xsl:value-of select="argument/value"/></value>
                    </uniqueArgument>
                 </xsl:for-each>
            </uniqueArguments>
            <templateId>
                <xsl:value-of select="templateId"></xsl:value-of>
            </templateId>
        </email>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which is giving me the following output..:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<email>
    <uniqueArguments>
        <uniqueArgument>
            <name>
                -url-
            </name>
            <value>
                http://localhost/iaf4asap/#/resetpassword/c0a82001--6b0373de_15eb8270a5e_-7fea</value>
            </uniqueArgument>
        </uniqueArguments>
    <templateId>
        c02f1e50-d569-41d9-87ec-933cded8a330
    </templateId>
</email>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping on only one node `arguments`, xsl:for-each required a XPath with many nodes in result, use instead :

```
<xsl:for-each select="arguments/argument">
```